# Is there a Python equivalent of Ruby's 'any?' function?

Tags: python, ruby, list

In Ruby, you can call [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003132) on a enumerable object to see if any of its elements satisfies the predicate you pass in the block. Like so:

```
lst.any?{|e| pred(e) }
```

In Python, there's an `any` function that does something similar, but on a list of booleans.

Of course, for a reasonably-sized list, I'd just do:

```
any(map(pred,lst))
```

However, if my list is very long, I don't want to have to do the entire `map` operation first.

So, the question: Is there a *generic* short-circuiting `any` function in Python?

Yes, I know it's really trivial to write one myself, but I'd like to use speedy builtin functions (and also not reinvent any wheels).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
any(pred(x) for x in lst)
```

alternatively

```
from itertools import imap
any(imap(pred, lst))
```

Comment: @perimosocordiae: Generator expressions.